# Toggle xRay for selected object in Maya with script

Tags: maya, mel

I'm new to mel script. I know that I can toggle manually xray with the code.

```
displaySurface -xRay true; //Xray on
displaySurface -xRay false; //Xray off
```

But I want it to toggle automatically, like

```
if(xRay on)
 set xRay off
else
 set xRay on
```

I know that I can check xRay on or off with the command

```
displaySurface -query -xRay;
```

But I just can't put this command into `if block`. I tried many things like the code below, but nothing works.

```
if(`displaySurface -query -xRay` == 1) // Error: line 1: Cannot use data of type int[] in a scalar operation. // 
print("To be or not to be");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `displaySurface -query -xRay` is returning an array. This worked for me:

```
int $y[] = `displaySurface -query -xRay`;

if( $y[0] == 1) 
print("To be or not to be");
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets after `int` in the error `Cannot use data of type int[]` indicates that the function returns an integer array. So you need to take the first element `[0]` of the array.

```
$xRayOnArray = `displaySurface -q -xRay`;
if ($xRayOnArray[0] == 0) {
    print("X-Ray is enabled");
} else {
    print("X-Ray is disabled");
}
```

Why it returns an array is a puzzle. It isn't documented and the function can only query a single object at a time.